# PHP SLIM not accepting dot(.) in uri argument

Tags: php, slim

I've trying to build an profanity filtering API by using slim. Here is the link of that api.

```
Link : http://www.employeeexperts.com/Profanity/index.php/rest/check/hello
```

At the end of the link, i'm appending the word 'hello' for profanity checking. Till now, it's working properly. But, the moment i added any dot(.) at the end of word (ex: hello..) , Slim redirecting the control to index page.

My GET router code is like this..

```
$app->get('/service/:method/:str', function ($method, $str) use ($app) {    
     // Internal codes goes here
});
```

Can any one help me fig out how i can stop this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default GET router doesn't let you have URLs ending in a dot. If you have any character after the dot, the page will function normally. As an alternative you could try a custom route condition as shown here:
http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Conditions

Example for your case:

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/service/:method/:str', function ($year) {
    echo "You are viewing archives from $year";
})->conditions(array('str' => '([a-z]+)', 'str' => '(.*)'));
```

If you are planing on processing complex data with your API (like complete articles or similar) I would suggest transferring the data via POST. It saves you a lot of headaches.

Comment: That condition is not working. About sending data in POST method, i'm also thinking that will be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, this is my solution:

```
$app->get('/service/+args', function ($args) use ($app) {    
    $arguments = str_replace("/service/", $app->request->getPathInfo());
    $args = explode('/', $arguments);
    var_dump($args);
});
```

When I access to URL `/service/foo/bar`, the `$args` will be like this:

```
array(
    'foo',
    'bar',
)
```

Also, when I access to URL `/service/foo/bar/baz/qux`, the `$args` will be like this:

```
array(
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz',
    'qux',
)
```